# What is the best replacement for python setup.py install when Cython needs to be compiled?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

With the latest version of [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/index.html), the `python setup.py install` command is being deprecated (see https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for more info).

```
(venv) [jon@dev02 py38]$ python setup.py install
running install
/home/jon/.jenkins/workspace/Farm_revision_linux_py36/TOXENV/py38/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-
packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is 
deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
/home/jon/.jenkins/workspace/Farm_revision_linux_py36/TOXENV/py38/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-
packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:156: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install 
command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
... etc
```

It is suggested that you can just `pip install .` to install a package from source, but this does not compile any Cython code. What is the best method for doing this?

The [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html) docs are still recommending use of `setup.py` and I can't find any better suggestions. It appears that a developer install (`pip install -e .`) does compile the Cython files, or you can `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` after running `pip install .`. Neither of these options are ideal, so I would like to know if there is a suggested alternative.

EDIT:

The package setup.py file contains this code, which should compile the Cython files:

```
try:
    import numpy
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
    cython_files = ["farm/rasters/water_fill.pyx"]
    cython_def = cythonize(cython_files, annotate=True,
                           compiler_directives={'language_level': str(sys.version_info.major)})
    include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()]
except ImportError:
    cython_def = None
    include_dirs = None
```

When installing with `python setup.py install`, the farm/rasters directory contains the following files:

```
water_fill.c
water_fill.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
water_fill.html
water_fill.pyx
```

When installing with `pip install .`, the directory does not contain the .so file and when we try and run water_fill tests, we get errors like this

```
________________________________ TestFlowDown1D.test_distribute_1d_trough_partial_3 _________________________________
farm/rasters/tests/test_flood_enhance.py:241: in test_distribute_1d_trough_partial_3
    actual_arr = water_fill.water_fill_1d(arr, additional_value)
E   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'water_fill_1d'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `pip install .` does compile Cython code (if compilation is part of the setup.py) but it installs the result into the site-packages of the active environment (this is what install means).

Comment: Thanks, but I can assure you it doesn't. We have a call to `cythonize` in our setup.py (as stated in the docs), but it is only exercised with `python setup.py install`. Using `pip install .` does not call it.

Comment: How can you say it doesn’t? What is then installed? If you make a syntax error in the pyx-file you should see an error when running pip install.

Comment: Just to make sure, my GitHub action setups use pip install . To build and install cython packages.

Comment: See edit: it does not compile the .so file that is needed to run the code.

Comment: It does, but in a temp folder after which the *so-files are copied to the  python installation. To prove, delete  set `include_dirs = []`, run `pip install .` you will see errors from compiler that numpy isn't found. If not, I'm afraid I cannot help you, as my setuptools works quite different than yours.

Comment: Ok, I've looked at the verbose output and it does appear pip creates a .so file, copies it into a temp wheel then installs it to site-packages. Maybe the problem is with pytest not finding it. I'll keep investigating this, but my original question still stands. Is this the best way of installing the package?

Comment: The `pip install` command is the best way to install the package and it does perform the installation of native extensions just fine, assuming your setup script configures it correctly. So @ead's comments already answer that. Why the installation fails _in your particular case_ is hard to answer without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: I can see what the problem is now - it's due to Python's import mechanism preferring to import a package from a subfolder in the cwd rather than the installed package of the same name.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the warning should go away if you keep the `setup.py` but add a `pyproject.toml`.
This is described in https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html .

Here is the example `pyproject.toml` file they give:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "Cython"]
```

Comment: You mean the deprecation warning? As it says above, the warning goes away if you use `pip install .` instead of `python setup.py install`.  We haven't got round to using pyproject.toml yet and it works just fine without it.

Comment: Maybe its a pip version thing, I get depreciation warnings if I only have a setup.py